# Iteration through tokens in a string

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, cmd, iteration, token

I am trying to simple iterate through a string using my delimiter. I am a bit confused on how this works. I want to take each token and actually add it into its own path so I need to process them seperately. How do I iterate through the token list until its no more for a loop or count my tokens before a loop so I can input a stop point ? I'm lost here...

Basically I need a way to access each file extension in that list, which I wont know the size of until an input right before.

I've tried everything I could think of. MAybe I am not getting how cmd loops work

```
for /f "delims=, " %%i in ("*.ok, *.pl, *.jc, *.ff") do (
echo %%i 
)
```

Comment: With a for /f you split into tokens (default is tokens=1) to get all you'll need "tokens=4delims=, " and then use %%i to %%l. You probaply meant a simple for and quote every element for them not being expanded. `for %%i in ("*.ok", "*.pl", "*.jc", "*.ff") do echo %%i`

Comment: Yes, [`for /F`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) splits a string into tokens, but it does not iterate through them, it returns all specified tokens (default: `tokens=1`) in a single loop iteration (e. g., having `tokens=1-3` returns the 1st token in `%%i`, the 2nd one in `%%j` and the 3rd one in `%%k` when `%%i` is explicitly given before `in`); the `delims` option defines all *characters*, *not* strings, that are used to separate the tokens, so you are specifying the comma and the space; consecutive delimiters are used as one; type `for /?`into a command prompt window and read the help text...

Comment: Note, wildcards are expanded: `for %%i in (*.ok) do echo %%i will list all files matching the mask `*.ok` (same as `dir /b *.ok`) You might (or might not) want to switch to `for %%i in (ok pl jc ff) do echo *.%%i`